# Bounded Operator and p-norm (more difficult than it seems).

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}$ be real vector spaces (with the usual operations of addition and scalar multiplication in each one of them) with the norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|_p$ for the space $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $|\mathbf{x}|$ for the space $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear operator (linear map from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$).
I want to show that $T$ is continuous and find the $\|T\|$.

What I do is the following:
Let $e_1,...,e_k$ be the usual base of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $\mathbb{R}^k\ni\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_ie_i$ then $|T(\mathbf{x})|=|\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_iT(e_i)|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_i||T(e_i)|\leq(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x|^p_i)^\frac{1}{p}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}=$ $\|\mathbf{x}\|_p(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}$
thus $T$ is bounded and so is continuous with $\|T\|\leq(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}$ (in a step above I used Hölder's Inequality with $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$).

I want to show that $\|T\|\geq(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}$ this will give me $\|T\|=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}$. After that I have no clue what to do.

Comment: You'll need to use [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) at some point.  You are looking for the [dual norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm) to the $\ell^p$ norm, and the answer is that we get the $\ell^q$ norm where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Comment: I used Hölder's Inequality. Did you see it?

Comment: Oh, yes, there it is. I didn't read the question carefully.  What we want now is an example vector.

Comment: I can't find this example vector, I tried so hard.

Comment: If $T = v^T = \pmatrix{v_1&\cdots&v_n}$ (when represented as a matrix), it suffices to take
$$
x = \frac{v}{\|v\|_{p}}
$$

Comment: But this gives $\frac{|T(x)|}{\|x\|_p}=|\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{v}{\|v\|_{p}}T(e_i)|$ and not $(\sum_{i=1}^{k}(T(e_i))^q))^\frac{1}{q}$.

Answer (score 0):

If I set $x_i=|T(e_i)|^{q-1}$ when $T(e_i)>0$ and $x_i=-|T(e_i)|^{q-1}$ when $T(e_i)<0$ then $x_iT(e_i)=|T(e_i)|^q$ and $\frac{|T(\mathbf{x})|}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_p}=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|T(e_i)|^q)^\frac{1}{q}$, for $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_k)$.